# instantiating a new xib programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

On clicking button below code is called, but my weeklyReviewViewController.xib is not loading but the application is logging out onto the initial view controller.

```
if(buttonIndex == 0){
    NSLog(@"0");
    [self.viewController initWithNibName:@"WeeklyReviewViewController" bundle:nil];
    navcnt = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    NSLog(@"navigation controller %@",navcnt);
    notificationCounter = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = navcnt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check that type of self.viewController is same as that of WeeklyReviewViewController.